# Splitting field of an 8th degree polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

I am trying to find the splitting field of the polynomial $p(x)=4 x^{8} - 8x^{6} - 12x^{4} - 40x^{2} - 160$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Here’s my attempt:

Let $u=x^{2}$. We can factor out a $4$ so we get $4(u^{4} - 2u^{3} - 3u^{2} - 10u - 40)$. Using the Rational Roots Theorem, we can divide $p(x)$ by some obvious factor. One of the factors is $u + 2$.

$$\frac{u^{4}-2u^{3}-3u^{2}-10u-40}{u+2} = u^{3}-4u^{2}+5u-20$$

So we have $(u+2)(u^{3}-4u^{2}+5u-20)$. We can factor by grouping and get
$4(u+2)(u-4)(u^{2}+5)$. Setting this equal to zero, we get our quasi solutions $x= \pm i \sqrt{2},\pm 2, \pm (-5)^{1/4}$.

Letting $\zeta_{4}^{k}=e^{2ki\pi/4}$, we have

$$\begin{split}
\zeta_4&=e^{2i\pi/4}=i\\ \zeta_4^{2}&=e^{4i\pi/4}=-1\\
\zeta_4^3&=e^{6i\pi/4}=i\\
\zeta_4^4&=1
\end{split}$$

So our final solutions are  $x= \pm i\sqrt{2},\pm 2, \pm \sqrt[4]{-5},\zeta_{4} \left(\pm (-5)^{1/4}\right)$.

Does this mean our splitting field is $\text{Split}_{\mathbb{Q}}\big(p(x)\big)=
\mathbb{Q}\left(2,\sqrt{2},(-5)^{1/4},\zeta_{4}\right)?$

Comment: Latex was being wierd. Some of the text is not where it’s supposed to be.

Comment: If you're doing this on a mobile device, LaTeX frequently puts bits of longer expressions in the wrong place. We just have to live with it until they upgrade.

Comment: 8 roots: $\:x=\pm2,
x=\pm\sqrt{2}i,
\:x=\pm(\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}}{\sqrt{2}}i),
\:x=\pm(-\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt[4]{5}}{\sqrt{2}}i)$ in general.

Comment: @Sapphire_Gaming21 I edited it to make it a bit more readable - though I am not sure that it was necessarily a great improvement. I have not quite seem an issue with it typesetting a fourth root so poorly, so I replaced it with a power notation. I am unsure exactly why it was not appearing as TeX would normally typeset such a root.

Comment: Remember that it might be possible to simplify the final answer. For example, $2\in\mathbb{Q}$, so there is no reason to write $\mathbb{Q}(2,\cdots)$. Also, if  $\zeta_4=i$, there's no reason not to refer to it as such in the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have shown we have
$$
p(x)=4(x^4 + 5)(x^2 + 2)(x + 2)(x - 2).
$$
Now we can read off the roots and find the splitting field. We can write $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{2},\sqrt[4]{5})$. The degree is $16$ over $\Bbb Q$.